# Displaying menu bar in Webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu in which some of the menu should be on right and some of it must be on left.

[image: Something like this]

I'm able to do this using `BootStrap Framework`,I want to do this without it. Here is my code.

***HTML***

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    // <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="pull-left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

***CSS***

```
    .nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can make navigation menubar without **Bootstrap**.Here,I make Demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/33ovfgeL/

```
   <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="pull-left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
  .nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.pull-left{float:left}
.pull-right{float:right}
.clear{clear:both}
.container{background-color:#bbb}
```

Comment: it just clears the float effect so next elements won't affected by float.

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate/define your CSS rules: Pull-right/Pull-left aren't defined in anyway along with the majority of your classes.

*You tagged your question with Twiiter-Bootstrap which most of these classes are used in.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.nav {
  margin-left: -35px;
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
ul.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
ul.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav ul > li > a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="pull-left">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Categories</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Register</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use any framework. I want to do using attributes alone in my css file.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or not then because your question is tagged twitter-bootstrap.

Comment: No,I'm not using it. I just want to indicate that I get the solution with bootstrap. Can I know how to do without it?

Comment: Yes, you can easily Google how to do this. You do not need StackOverflow for it. See my updated answer.